# C++ For Loop got skipped in the middle of the process. How to fix it?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

My Second FOR loop got skipped by itself in the middle of the process. Can you help me to fix this?

I've been trying to search on the web but none of them help me.

```
int n = 9;
int arr[] = {10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20};

int temp = 0;
int skip[99];
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i == skip[i])
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = arr[i];
        for (int j = i+1; j<n - i; j++)
        {
            if (temp == arr[j])
            {
                total += 1;
                skip[j] = j;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout << total;
```

the result should be `3`, but what I got is `2` because the loop is skipped in the middle of the process.

Comment: The array int skip[99]; is not initialized. So the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: And why the result should be equal to 3?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the result equal to 3 because every same number is count as 1, if you see the index number (0 == 3), (4 == 7), (1 == 2). There's why the result should be 3.

Comment: What should the program calculate?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow How many same numbers in the array, but every same number should count as 1

Comment: Then you have only 2 same numbers 1 and 2.

Comment: You must explain what you are trying to do in your question.

Comment: @AkhdanRasiq -- So you want to know how many unique numbers there are in that array?

Comment: Off-topic: `if(c) { continue; } else { /* stuff */ }` is much nicer written as simply `if(!c) { /* stuff */ }` (i. e. `if(i != skip[i])` in your case). Variant, if you want to spare indentation: `if(c) { continue; } /* no else here, you continued before anyway... */ /* stuff */`.

Comment: Sidenote: if you change array size, you need to change n explicitly. You can spare this if you have `arr[] = { /*...*/ }; int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);`, then n will adjust itself appropriately. Even nicer would be `std::array`, coming with its own `size` member (you don't need the division trick as with raw arrays and `sizeof`).

Comment: [Click Here to see the picture](https://s3.amazonaws.com/hr-challenge-images/25168/1474122392-c7b9097430-sock.png) @VladfromMoscow this is what I expect for the result, I apologize for not making my question clear, I will be better next time I ask a question.

Comment: `if(c) { } else { continue; }` – and nothing after the else. Well, what do you think would run differently if you just dropped the else?

Comment: @AkhdanRasiq See my updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not make sense and moreover has undefined behavior at least because the array `skip`

```
int skip[99];
```

is not initialized.

You did not describe in your question what program must to do. So at first I thought that it seems that you need to determine the number of unique elements in an array and suggested the following solutions.

The assignement can be easy done using the standard container `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20 };

    size_t total = std::set<int>( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ) ).size();

    std::cout << total << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4
```

because there are four unique numbers in the array: `10, 20, 30, 50`.

If you need to use only loops then the program can look the following way.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    size_t total = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j != i && a[j] != a[i] ) j++;

        if ( j == i ) ++total;
    }

    std::cout << total << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Again its output is

```
4
```

However now after adding comments to the question you need to count the number of pairs of equal elements in the array.

If so then you can use for example the standard container `std::map` the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20 };
    size_t total = 0;

    std::map<int, size_t> m;

    for ( const auto &item : a ) ++m[item];

    for ( const auto &item : m ) total += item.second / 2;

    std::cout << total << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
```

And again if you may use only loops then the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    size_t total = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t count = 0;
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[i] == a[j] ) ++count;
        }

        if ( count % 2 == 1 ) ++total;
    }

    std::cout << total << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3
```

Comment: `const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );` or `const size_t N = std::size( a );` in C++17.

Comment: Alternative variants: 1. sorting the array first, then sum of lenghts of sequences of equal numbers devided by 2 will result in the number of pairs found; 2. iterating over the entries, `std::map m; for(...) { ++m[entry]; }`, the sum of the halves of the values in the map is the number of pairs...

Comment: thank you so much for your help, this is what I looking for, next time I will more careful to make my question is understandable.

Comment: @Aconcagua I rely on that the original array may not be sorted.:)